# How to make a React Function infer a typescript type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm kinda new to typescript, I cannot say that I'm loving it, but as I'm doing a library it was a good idea to test it a little more.

I'm having a problem typing a Function, I tried with generic types with no success. Basically, I have a component that receives a `list` and an `onRender` function.

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Iterator<ItemsOnListType>(
  props: IteratorPropTypes<ItemsOnListType>,
) {
  const { list, onRender } = props;
  return <>{list.map(onRender)}</>;
}
```

Its types:

```
interface IteratorPropTypes<T> {
  list: Array<T>;
  onRender: (prop: T, index: number, originalList: Array<T>) => JSX.Element;
}
```

But, on its test file, the prop and index are not typed, they show `any` type. I want a good fix for this problem, I'm probably missing something, I basically want that onRender props work like the `Array.map` function that can infer its type from the array. The code is available here https://github.com/WilliamCSA04/React-Useful-Components/tree/master/src/components/Iterator

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, you just forget to export your type and import it in Iterator.tsx. Although there is no error, `IteratorPropTypes` is actually pointing to global namespace which is not correct.

**Iterator.type.ts**

```js
export interface IteratorPropTypes<T> { // export type
  list: Array<T>;
  onRender: (prop: T, index: nzumber, originalList: Array<T>) => JSX.Element;
}
```

**Iterator.tsx**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { IteratorPropTypes } from './Iterator.types'; // import type

export default function Iterator<ItemsOnListType>(
  props: IteratorPropTypes<ItemsOnListType>,
) {
  const { list, onRender } = props;
  return <>{list.map(onRender)}</>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it did work, I just can't get why Typescript allows me to use it without importing if it does not work properly.

Comment: because typescript treats it as global namespace which is no meaning at all.